# CMD script - Truncate string in a for loop

Tags: string, loops, for-loop, cmd, truncate

My input is a text file (itemLabels.txt) which contains 4 lines with strings like:

Label **4.3.23** against time Thu Feb 13 16:30:37 EST 2014

Label **R4.4** against time Fri Jul 25 08:00:00 EDT 2014 with comment Released 7/26/2014

Label **976053_Release4_5** against time Tue Oct 14 11:04:53 EDT 2014

Label **My 4th Label** against time Tue Feb 24 19:23:05 EST 2015 with comment as of today

I need to extract all the highlighted string between "Label" and "against". I have tried a simple script like:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in (itemLabels.txt) do (
    set Label=%%b
    set Label=!Label:* against =!
    echo !Label!
)
```

This, however, removes everything before the " against " word. Is there any way to truncate everything AFTER " against " and return the string? Replacing that line with a * after the " against " doesn't work...

```
set Label=!Label: against *=!
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to "*tokenize the rest of the line by* `against time` *and get the first token*". Too bad the `for /f ...` command can only split by single character(s).

But you can first replace that string with some single character (one you are sure will not occur in the label name, I chose `*`), then split it by that:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in (itemLabels.txt) do (
    set Label=%%b
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=*" %%c in ("!Label: against time =*!") do (
        echo %%c
    )
)
```

Comment: I am still miffed that a wildcard character (*) can be used BEFORE a string that I want to replace, but not AFTER!

Comment: Yeah, it sucks that the asterisk works as a prefix only. At least it's documented properly in the `set /?` help page and there is no doubt.